# With jQuery, how to properly register an "onchange" callback with one argument?

Tags: jquery, events, callback, arguments, onchange

Consider this example of registering onchange callbacks:

```
function appendToSaveArray(field)
{
    saveArray[field.attr("id")] = field.attr("value");
}

$('#fields input').change(appendToSaveArray);
```

The idea is storing the last change made to several text inputs in an array.
When I change the value of one of the inputs (and then switch the focus to another element of the document), the function `appendToSaveArray` is called.
However, the argument `field` does not contain the input element where the change was triggered, which I would have expected.
How can I find out from within the function `appendToSaveArray`, what input triggered the event?

Comment: _"However, the argument field does not contain anything sensible"_ - Sure it does, it contains the `event` object, exactly like the doco says it will.

Comment: @nnnnnn, fair comment, edited.

Comment: Actually I feel a little guilty about referring to the doco like that, because although the doco for the `.change()` method does clearly state what the parameter is it doesn't really talk about the fact that `this` is the element the event occurred on, and even the doco for the more generic `.bind()` and `.on()` methods buries that information a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `change` event handler, `this` refers to the input for whom the event was triggered. You can get its value directly with `this.value`:

```
function appendToSaveArray()
{
    saveArray[this.id] = this.value;
}

$('#fields input').change(appendToSaveArray);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5SyMB/)**.

Comment: Or use saveArray[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val() instead.

Comment: @niaher: That'd work too, but imho, there's no need to add the overhead of jQuery just to get two properties.

Answer (score 1):

`field`, in your code, contains the event object. In your function, use `$(this)`instead.

Also note you can simplify this code as a one-liner with an anonymous function :

```
$('#fields input').click(function () { saveArray[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val(); });
```

Comment: As long as we're simplifying, why not `saveArray[this.id] = this.value;`?

Answer (score 1):

`field` equals the event, which also stores the event target, ie. the element changed :

```
function appendToSaveArray(field) {
    saveArray[field.target.id] = field.target.value;
}

$('#fields input').on('change', appendToSaveArray);​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kr5gC/)